# $g \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is identically zero outside $B_r(0)$ with $r$ fixed $\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $g \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is identically zero outside $B(0,r)$ with $r$ fixed in $ \mathbb{R}$, and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g = 1$. For $h>0$, define $g_h(x)=g(x/h)h^{-d}$.

I'm trying to prove that
$$
\int_{B(0,hr)} g_h(x)dx=1
$$

It seems quite obvious, but I don't really know how to start.

Comment: Start by replacing $g_h(x)$ with $g(x/h)h^{-d}$, then perform the change of variable $u = x/h$ (note: $du = h^{-d} dx$)

Comment: Can we do the change of variable, since it is a Lebesgue integral?

Answer (score 1):

With $\phi(x) = {1 \over h} x$ we have $D\phi(x) = {1 \over h} I$ and so
$| \det D\phi(x) | = {1 \over h^d}$.

Let $A = B(0,hr)$ and apply the change of variables [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables):

Then $\int_{\phi(A)} g = \int_A g(\phi(x)) | \det D\phi(x) | dx = \int_A {1 \over h^d} g(\phi(x)) dx = \int_A g_h(x) dx $.

Comment: Can we think of the function $g=g^+ + g^-$ as being approximated individually by a set of simple functions $\phi_{k} = \sum_{n=1}^{N_{k}} c_n \mathbb{1}_{E_n}$? And then $g_h = g_h^+  + g_h^-$ can be also approximated by $\phi_{k} ' = \sum_{n=1}^{N_k} c_n \mathbb{1}_{E_n'}$ with $E_n' = \{x/h|x \in E_n\}$. Thanks

Comment: @ChristophorusX: You can, but why?